# Can't add date to a sql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

I'm to add date to a database. The database field is of type DATE and I'm passing in a String with the date in it. Here is the sql:

```
INSERT INTO timetableslot (TO_DATE('?', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), time, classID, cost)
VALUES ('12/23/2016','12:00',3,12)
```

I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '('?', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), time, classID, cost)VALUES
>   ('12/23/2016','12:00',3,12)' at line 1

```
public boolean saveToDatabase() {

    boolean saved = false;
    Connection c = DBHelperClass.getConnection();
    String template = "INSERT INTO timetableslot (TO_DATE('?', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), time, classID, cost)"
            + "VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    if (c != null) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement inserter = c.prepareStatement(template);
            inserter.setString(1, this.getDate());
            inserter.setString(2, this.getTime());
            inserter.setInt(3, this.getClassID());
            inserter.setInt(4, this.getCost());

            System.out.println(inserter);
            inserter.executeUpdate();
            saved = true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    return saved;
}
```

Comment: Name of the column will come instead of `TO_DATE('?', 'MM/DD/YYYY')`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following as your prepared statement:

```
String template = "INSERT INTO timetableslot (<COLUMN-NAME>, time, classID, cost) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE(?, '%m/%d/%Y'),?,?,?)";
```

`TO_DATE` is a Oracle function. MySQL uses `STR_TO_DATE`.

Comment: Hi when I enter that in I get:

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3).

Comment: Hey @Pavol, did you replace `<COLUMN-NAME>` by the name of your date column?

Comment: I have yes         String template = "INSERT INTO timetableslot (date, time, classID, cost) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('?', '%m/%d/%y'),?,?,?)";

Comment: Try removing apostrophes from `?` in `STR_TO_DATE`. Resulting in `STR_TO_DATE(?, '%m/%d/%y')`.

Comment: that sort of worked: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect date value: '12/28/2016'